# Использование одного коннекта в разных потоках

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Можно ли использовать один коннект в разных потоках в моей ситуации? Будут ли какие-либо негативные последствия, кроме того что запросы будут стоять в очереди? Либо лучше все-таки каждый раз создавать и открывать новый коннект (в таком случае пугает их количество). Или обязательно использование пула коннектов?

```
    public partial class Service : ServiceBase
{
    OleDbConnection conn;
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {            
        conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.Open();
        timer1 = new Timer();
        this.timer1.Interval = 3000;
        this.timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SOME SQL QUERY", conn);
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();//запрос занимает времени ~50мс
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read()) //на практике порядка 6 итераций
            {
                List<object> obj = new List<object>();
                obj.Add(conn);
                obj.Add(reader["Column1"].ToString());
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((s) => { BackgroundJob(obj); }));
            }
        }
    }
    private static void BackgroundJob(object obj)
    {
        List<object> args = (List<object>)obj;
        OleDbConnection conn = (OleDbConnection)args[0];
        string data = (string)args[1];
        //...do main job
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SOME SQL QUERY", conn);//запрос занимает времени ~20мс
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запросы не будут стоять в очереди. Ну или иногда будут стоять в очереди, а иногда - падать с исключением. При использовании одного соединения вам обеспечены долгие и увлекательные вечера отладки багов, которые воспроизводятся в зависимости от фазы луны.

OleDbConnection, как и другие IDbConnection-классы, не приспособлен для работы с ним из нескольких потоков. И вообще не предназначен для долгого удержания в открытом состоянии.

[Пулинг для OleDbConnection включен по умолчанию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms254502(v=vs.110).aspx), поэтому если вы будете создавать новый OleDbConnection при необходимости, и закрывать его сразу после выполнения команды - количество реально открытых соединений будет очень мало. Для кода выше - это 1-2 соединения.

Не стоит писать потенциально бажный код, заморачиватся с передачей везде соединения, с потенциальными проблемами при обрыве соединения и прочим ради проблемы которой на самом деле нет.

Comment: Спасибо, очень полезная информация на счет пулинга для OleDbConnection, тогда конечно буду создавать  новый OleDbConnection каждый раз